# Check number of records in a database table other than count(*)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to check if there are any records in a table for a certain entry. I used `COUNT(*)` to check the number of records and got it to work. However, when the number of records for an entry is very high, my page loads slowly.

I guess `COUNT(*)` is causing the problem, but how do I check if the records exist without using it? I only want to check whether any records exist for the entry and then execute some code. Please help me find an alternative solution for this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post the SQL you are trying. It is probably not the Count but more likely your joins or indexes causing the problems.

Comment: Agreed, check your joins, I've always used it fine, an alternative to count(*) is SUM(case when [yourcondition] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), but count should be faster.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways that may work. You can use exists, which lets the database optimise the method to get the answer:

```
if exists(select * from ...)
```

You can use top 1 so that the database can stop after finding the first match:

```
if (select count(*) from (select top 1 * from ...)) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

use select top 1 and check is there is an row

Answer (score 3):

You can try selecting the first entry for given condition.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE <condition> LIMIT 1
```

I'm not sure if this will be quicker but you can try.

Other possible solution. How do you use count? `COUNT(*)`? If yes, then try using `COUNT(id)`. As I remember this should be faster.

Comment: Using count(id) may actually be slower than count(*), and they don't work the same. Using count(*) gives you the number of rows, but count(id) gives you the number of non-null values of id so it has to check the value of each row.

Comment: I assumed that `id` is a primary key that cannot be NULL. But in other case you are completely right.

Comment: @Guffa: that's fine if `id` is a primary or unique key though, since it can't be null. I assume SQL implementations are smart enough to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend testing to see if at least 1 record exists in the table, that meets your criteria then continue accordingly. For example:

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Table_Name --Or Your ColumnName
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables -- Or your TableName
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'At least one record exists in table'
END
```

Comment: No need for a top 1 inside an IF EXISTS. IF EXISTS will quite when it finds the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on codeproject. It's quite handy.

```
-- Author,,Md. Marufuzzaman

SELECT SYS_OBJ.NAME AS "TABLE NAME"
     , SYS_INDX.ROWCNT AS "ROW COUNT"
FROM SYSOBJECTS SYS_OBJ, SYSINDEXES SYS_INDX

WHERE SYS_INDX.ID = SYS_OBJ.ID
  AND INDID IN(0,1) --This specifies 'user' databases only
  AND XTYPE = 'U' --This omits the diagrams table of the database
--You may find other system tables will need to be ommitted,
 AND SYS_OBJ.NAME <> 'SYSDIAGRAMS'

ORDER BY SYS_INDX.rowcnt DESC --I found it more useful to display 
--The following line adds up all the rowcount results and places
--the final result into a separate column [below the first resulting table]
COMPUTE SUM(SYS_INDX.ROWCNT) 

GO
```

Comment: This gives you an idea whether any rows exist in the table or not - but **NOT** whether there are any rows with a particular EntryID value or anything like that.

Answer (score -1):

you should use

select count(1) from

If you are saying (*) it will expand all the column's and then count

Comment: certainly not true for Oracle.